# Does the android license allow handset manufacturers to build an OS that is proprietary?

Tags: license-compatibility, android

Does the Android license, being Apache license, permit others to develop their own versions of Android and license them as proprietary? As far as I understand, the Linux kernel on which Android is built is GPL. Then how can Android or further derivatives be released under a different license? What is the sanctity of GPL license of Linux here?

Comment: Very closely related: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5074/whats-android-license-if-its-not-free

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Android kernel is a variant of the Linux kernel.  Since the latter is GPLv2, the former must also be, and it is.  So the "*sanctity*" of the GPL on the Android kernel is intact; you can get the source for those portions at [places like this](https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers#honeycomb-gpl-modules).  If you make and distribute your own modified version you will also have source-distribution obligations to honour.  However, the licence on the kernel has no effect on what you can run on it: I can run Apache-licensed, GPLv3-licensed, and proprietary software packages in user space on top of my Linux desktop kernel, without offending against the kernel's licence.

The userspace OS is under the Apache licence.  This is a weak copyleft licence, and taking the code and making proprietary products from it is lawful, provided you adhere to a few [notification-related](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) obligations (remember, IANAL/IANYL).

The applications that run on Android can be under any licence their developers choose.